# Magic Fields Get Group

Tags: php, wordpress

I am ahving trouble getting Magic Fields to recognise the get_group function for the following code, any help for code changing to make this recognise this code would be really helpful. What I am trying to do is write 'add a sidebar box and image box which is within the group Sidebar -  or otherwise if not present include dynamic sidebar'

```
<?php if ( get_group('Sidebar',TRUE) ) { ?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
    <?php echo get_group('Sidebar'); ?>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: get_group('Sidebar',TRUE)? 2nd parameter to get_group is post_id http://wiki.magicfields.org/doku.php?id=front-end_functions_v20#get_group

Comment: So would it be like this?: `code`   <?php if (get_group('Sidebar')) { ?>
    <div id="primary" class="widget-area">
   

<?php echo get('sidebar_text'); ?>
<?php echo get('sidebar_image'); ?>

    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>`code`

Answer (score 0):

you can use "?:" to use a defult value if the first value dosn't exist, like:

```
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
    <?php echo get_group('Sidebar') ?: dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ); ?>
</div>
```

or for you whit php version lower then 5.3, before the "?:"

```
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
    <?php
        $sidebar = get_group('Sidebar');
        echo $sidebar ? $sidebar : dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it shows no content on any page, and causes the footer to not work so the code must be failing.

Comment: maybe you have an to old version of php